# Getting AccessViolationException while Assigning Delegate from C# to FunctionPointer in NativeCode

Tags: c#, c++, delegates, pinvoke, function-pointers

From C# code I'm trying to call a API from a *.c file. But I'm getting `AccessViolationException`.

Earlier I was getting `BadImageFormatException`, but I solved it by putting both the exe and the dll together in one location.

I suspect that it has something to do with `CallingConvention` of `Cdecl` or `StdCall` or with `PlatformType=x86` or `x64`.

In My C#. exe I've set the CPU to x86 and in my NativeCode.dll the calling convention is mentioned as Cdecl only.

I'm not able to understand that how to solve this issue,there are many posts on web explaining about this problem but somehow I'm not able to find any concrete solution to this issue.

In case of any more details please let me know.

Below mentioned is some code from files which can highlight the problem:

## Header.H file

```
typedef int BOOL;

#ifndef FALSE
#define FALSE               0
#endif

#ifndef TRUE
#define TRUE                1
#endif

typedef BOOL REGFUNCTION( char *pRegKey, char *pBuffer, int iBufSize );
```

## Implementation.c file

```
    #ifdef SWSCANCODE_EXPORTS
    #define SWSCANCODE_API __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
    #define SWSCANCODE_API __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif

    #ifdef SWSCAN_APIS

    SWSCANCODE_API BOOL SWSetGetRegKeyValue  ( REGFUNCTION* pGetRegKeyValue );

    #endif

    SWGLOBALS*     pSWGlobals; 

    SWSCANCODE_API BOOL SWSetGetRegKeyValue( REGFUNCTION * pGetRegKeyValue )
    {

       BOOL bInitStatus;                // initialization status

       bInitStatus = TRUE;              // assume initialization will be successful

       pSWGlobals->pGetRegKeyValue = pGetRegKeyValue;
       if(NULL!=pSWGlobals->pGetRegKeyValue)
       {
           printf("I don't know");
       }
       return( bInitStatus );
    }
```

## C# code

```
class Program
{
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)] 
    public delegate int REGFUNCTION([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string pRegKey,  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string pBuffer, int iBufSize);

    [DllImport("NativeCode.dll", EntryPoint = "SWSetGetRegKeyValue", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    [return:MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern Boolean SWSetGetRegKeyValue(IntPtr pGetRegKeyValue);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        REGFUNCTION dele = GetRegKeyValue;
        IntPtr  ptr = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(dele);
        GC.KeepAlive(dele);
        bool bSetRegKeyValueOk = SWSetGetRegKeyValue(ptr);
    }

    public static int GetRegKeyValue(string pRegKey, string pBuffer, int iBufSize)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Successful in calling the method");
       return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your native code looks a bit strange, try: `typedef BOOL (*REGFUNCTION)( char *pRegKey, char *pBuffer, int iBufSize ); SWSCANCODE_API BOOL SWSetGetRegKeyValue( REGFUNCTION pGetRegKeyValue )` REGFUNCTION is already pointer, you don't need additional *

Comment: The native code is something which is fixed and it is from some third party libraries.It is totally working fine with the above mentioned signature in our old application(a legacy one).I'm trying to keep this 'C' logic as it is and change the caller logic from C++ to C#,so that's why this excercise. So the call from C# will replace the old C++ call to this 'C' code. I need to implement the correct way of calling in C#,this signature will not be changed as it might effect the native code functionality which we're not aware of.

Comment: Well, try to remove ref from PInvoke SWSetGetRegKeyValue declaration. I still believe that it should be a pointer and not double pointer.

Comment: Tried your solution but still the same error :( . The AccesViolationException is saying that read/write memory is corrupted,what can cause memory corruption in this code? Is the Delegate declaration or the variables assignment or the callingConvention?

Comment: I found the solution to this issue. Instead of passing delegate or method that the managed delegate encapsulate as a function pointer to the native code use the following code to pass the delegate as Function Pointer. I've modified the PInvoke code so that native code accepts IntPtr as a argument.  Please refer to the edited code for solution

Comment: Use the following post to go through the PInvoke in detailed yet clear manner. This will help the developers to clearly use the concepts when using PInvoke                    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx